# I am trying to make a tile layer be disabled in code Godot

Tags: godot, topdown

This is my current code:

```
extends TileMap

signal button1_1

func _on_activate_buton_body_entered(_body):
    button1_1.emit()
```

I want it to disable a door 1 layer in the tilemap when the on_activate_button function is triggered

i tried using chat gpt and i tried using the tilemap and .layers.Door1.enabled = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look in the documentation for [`TileMap`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tilemap.html#class-tilemap-method-set-layer-enabled) and reading the list of methods, should take you to [`set_layer_enabled`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tilemap.html#class-tilemap-method-set-layer-enabled):

> `void set_layer_enabled ( int layer, bool enabled )`
>
> Enables or disables the layer layer. A disabled layer is not processed at all (no rendering, no physics, etc...).
>
> If layer is negative, the layers are accessed from the last one.

We, of course, do not want to enable the layer, so we are going to pass `false` on the enable parameter.

Thus, you would disable a layer like this:

```
set_layer_enabled(layer_number, false)
```

For example, disabling the layer 1 would be:

```
set_layer_enabled(1, false)
```